# Loading Mask while switching between cards in a Card Layout using ExtJS

Tags: extjs

I am using a card layout in one of  my views. There are 6 cards in a card Layout. I use image clicks to switch between the cards. Since it takes sometime for the cards to switch from one to another I need to add a loading mask while switching i.e, when I click on the image the loading mask should appear and as soon as the next card is rendered the loading mask should be removed. Could anyone please suggest me a solution to the loading mask problem that I'm facing ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why the switching take times? Is because a store load? 
If is because the store you can show the mask in beforeLoad and hide in load event. Something like that:

```
Ext.define('MyApp.store.MyStore', {
...
myMask: null,
listeners: {
    beforeload: function(store, operation, options){
        this.myMask = new Ext.LoadMask(Ext.getBody(), {
            cls: "loader",
            msg: "Loading..."
        });
        this.myMask.show();
    },
    load: function(store, records, success, operation, options){
        this.myMask.hide();
    }
});
```

I dont know how you are doing the app. But if this can't help, you also can create a object with a mask and show always after click and you can hide in the "painted" event of the views:
http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2.2.0/#!/api/Ext.navigation.View-event-painted

[EDITED]

So you could override the Store to aways show de mask in the loading.
Here the code:

```
Ext.define('MyAppName.store.App', {
override: 'Ext.data.Store',

timeOut: null,

// List of stores that run in background (dont show mask)
backgroundStores: [
    'StoreOne',
    'StoreTwo'
],

constructor: function(config){
    this.callParent(arguments);
    this.on('beforeload', 'onBeforeLoad', this);
    this.on('load', 'onAfterLoad', this);
},

onBeforeLoad: function(store, operation, options){
    // runing in background
    if(this.backgroundStores.indexOf(store._storeId) != -1){
        return;
    }

    var re = new RegExp("MyAppName");
    // Fix a feature of sencha that do some request from store off app
    if(store._model == undefined || store._model.$className == undefined || re.exec(store._model.$className) == null){
        return;
    }

    MyAppName.app.config.mask.show(); // this is my mask defined in App.js

    // timout
    this.timeOut = setTimeout(function() {
        Ext.Msg.alert("Erro", "Could not connect to the server");
        MyAppName.app.config.mask.hide();
    }, 30000);
},
onAfterLoad: function(store, records, success, operation, options){
    if(this.backgroundStores.indexOf(store._storeId) != -1){
        return;
    }

    var re = new RegExp("MyAppName");
    if(store._model == undefined || store._model.$className == undefined || re.exec(store._model.$className) == null){
        return;
    }
    MyAppName.app.config.mask.hide();
    window.clearInterval(this.timeOut);
}});
```

Comment: Hi Scoup, Thanks for answering. Yes I'm using a store load. The store load takes time because I plot approximately 7 months data on the charts and the data for 7 months is really huge.

Comment: I added some code to you override your data.Store to aways show the mask when loading. You can improve your logic in it.